# How can I speed up batch creating of multiple related objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

I use this for simplicity. Let say I have 2 models here A and B.
I want to use `A.objects.bulk_create(a_list)` and `B.objects.bulk_create(b_list)` to batch create both `A` and `B` objects.
But, `B` reply on `A` and `user_id` should be the same. So, I have to batch creating those objects in a `for` loop like this:

```
for user_id in user_ids:
    a = A.objects.create(user_id=user_id, **kwargs)
    B.objects.create(a=a, user_id=user_id, **kwargs)
```

The problem is that the speed is too slow when the data is big and I wannt speed up. So, is there a workaround to implement this?

Comment: Please help to show a_list and b_list

Comment: `a_list` is something like `[(A(user_id=user_id, **kwargs))]`. And `b_list` is something like  `[(B(user_id=user_id, **kwargs))]`

Comment: Nice, no need use for loop, just use bulk_create for A first, then use bulk_create for B as well!

Comment: But B reply on A. If I bulk_create a_list, then what I get is `a_objects` without a `pk`.

Comment: Just answer this question, please help to check

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is create instances of A alongside the B, then no `bulk_create()` won't do this. However, if the instances of A already exist in the database then you could manually add their pk's to the list you pass to `bulk_create()`. Then the B instances will be created with the correct relations to A.

```
a_list = [(A(user_id=user_id, **kwargs))]
A.objects.bulk_create(a_list)

(make b_list like the line bellow)
b_list = [(B(a__id=...,user_id=user_id, **kwargs))]
B.objects.bulk_create(b_list)
```

Noted: All of this can be done inside a single `transaction.atomic` context.

Comment: Thx a lot. Currently I have to retrieve a_ids from `bulk_create` like this: `start = timezone.now()
a_ids = A.objects.filter(create_at__gt=start).values_list('id', flat=True))  # Get ids of A objects just created..`